# Connecting to Alfresco using IMAP from Zimbra webclient

Tags: imap, zimbra, alfresco

For one of our clients, we need to establish IMAP protocol between the mail server and an ALfresco server (EDMS server). The objectif is : from an email, a user can access to his files in the server, and from the EDMS server, can access to his mails.
Everything works perfect when using outlook desktop application. Nevertheless, our client uses Zimbra Web Client. When IMAP is configured, I can see all the folders and files in the mail, but any kind of interaction is possible after that. I cannot check a mail that I have moved under a folder from the server, and cannot check file that I add in the server from the mail.
I remind again that everything works perfectly when using Outlook Desktop.
Does anyone have an idea about it?
Please do not rate as unusefull it is important to me.
(excuse my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved.I'm posting this for others who may have the same issue :
The configuration in Alfresco is known : [Enabling Imap Alfresco](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/imap-enable.html)

Actually, Zimbra Web Client takes time to sync. Sometimes 2 hours. You can also force the synchronisation (there is a button in the web client to force the sync) but still it takes about 5 minutes.
To configure this :

1- Add a new external account. (email : your login to Alfresco, pwd : password associated to that login)

2- Imap address : alfresco address.

3- Port : the same configured in alfresco-global.properties.
Do not forget to verify firewall and settings so that Zimbra server and Alfresco server can communicate.

Comment: can you please mark your own answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Zimba web client but I'm 90% sure it is not (or at least not only) an  IMAP client.

The forum thread bellow tend to confirm, it is actually using HTTP for many things.
https://forums.zimbra.org/viewtopic.php?t=8710

Zimbra API was SOAP based back in the days and probably evolved to REST  nowadays, but that's still not IMAP.
IMHO there are very few chances to make that work based on IMAP.
However you can tell your customer that Alfresco provide a connector for Outlook (not sure it would work with Alfresco community and requires at least a recent 4.2) which allow to browse the Alfresco repository without using the old fashionned IMAP interface:

https://www.alfresco.com/products/ecm/integrations/alfresco-outlook-integration

That may be a good approach for him to give up on ZWC and benefit from a better integration of Alfresco.
Another wolution could be to set up a true IMAP based webmail, like e.g. [roundcube](http://roundcube.net)

Comment: I don't think that requesting to change the mail server is a good idea. But the links you send are usefull so thank you so much. After a deep inverstigation, it turns out that ZWC does not synchronise the changes in the IMAP folders. So we need to find a way to force it. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not requesting to change the mail server

Comment: If you setup the alfresco account as an external IMAP account in the ZWC it should sync. The synchronisation is actually done by the server and you should inspect the server log files to see if there is any problem with the IMAP account.